# Issues Overloading CTOR's in Scala

Tags: scala, constructor, overloading

Im having an issue over loading the constructors in Scala. Each time I try to pass a value for the over loaded CTOR I get the error

```
Example: 
    var client : Client = Client(*variable type List[String]()*);

 Unspecified value parameter clientList.
```

My goal is to have an object created using 2 different data types. One a NodeSeq and the Other a List. Never Both. Am I over loading the CTOR correctly or is there a more efficient way to achieve my goal?

```
package api
import xml._

case class Client(clientNode: NodeSeq, clientList: List[String]) {

  def this(clientNode: NodeSeq) = this(clientNode, null)
  def this(clientList: List[String]) = this(null, clientList)

  var firstName: String
  var lastName: String
  var phone: String
  var street: String
  var city: String
  var state: String
  var zip: String
  var products = List[String]()
  var serviceOrders = List[String]()

  if (clientList == null) {
    firstName = (clientNode \\ "firstname").text
    lastName = (clientNode \\ "lastname").text
    phone = (clientNode \\ "phone").text
    street = (clientNode \\ "street").text
    city = (clientNode \\ "city").text
    state = (clientNode \\ "state").text
    zip = (clientNode \\ "zip").text

    (clientNode \\ "products").foreach(i => products = i.text :: products)

    (clientNode \\ "serviceOrders").foreach(i => serviceOrders = i.text :: serviceOrders)

  } else {
    firstName = clientList(0)
    lastName = clientList(1)
    phone = clientList(2)
    street = clientList(3)
    city = clientList(4)
    state = clientList(5)
    zip = clientList(6)
  }

  override def toString(): String = {
    return "Name : " + firstName + " " + lastName +
      "\nAddress : " +
      "\n\t" + street +
      "\n\t" + city + ", " + state + " " + zip
  }

}
```

Comment: Don't use `null` in Scala code. It really only exists for interoperability with Java. Use `Option` instead. (Sorry, I have to say this every time I see someone using `null`...).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't post working code; you can't have undefined vars.

Anyway, the problem is that even though you have overridden the constructors, you have *not* overridden the builders in the companion object.  Add this and it will work the way you want:

```
object Client {
  def apply(clientNode: NodeSeq) = new Client(clientNode)
  def apply(clientList: List[String]) = new Client(clientList)
}
```

(if you're using the REPL, be sure to use `:paste` to enter this along with the case class so you add to the default companion object instead of replacing it).

But a deeper problem is that this is not the way you should be solving the problem.  You should define a trait that contains the data you want:

```
trait ClientData {
  def firstName: String
  def lastName: String
  /* ... */
}
```

and inherit from it twice, once for each way to parse it:

```
class ClientFromList(cl: List[String]) extends ClientData {
  val firstName = cl.head
  . . .
}
```

or you could turn the NodeSeq into a list and parse it there, or various other things.  This way you avoid exposing a bunch of vars which are probably not meant to be changed later.

Comment: Kerr is to Skeet as Scala is to C#. Did not know one could multi-apply, always something new in this language ;-)

Comment: @virtualeyes - I think that honor belongs to Danial C. Sobral, actually.

Comment: sure, but he's been on S.O. for a year longer than yourself ;-) Obviously there are a handful of Scala "rock stars" posting here, Daniel certainly one of them; the Skeet reference is not only knowledge, but quality-of-answer, where the student goes, "a-ha, now I get it!" @Oxbow Lakes is also quite good. Anyway, S.O. itself is the single best teaching/learning resource on the net; though I've graduated, I'm still in school ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Auxiliary constructors are for simple one-liners and aren't suitable in this case. More idiomatic way would be to define factory methods in a companion object:

```
case class Client(firstName: String,
                  lastName: String,
                  products: List[String] = Nil)

object Client {

  import scala.xml.NodeSeq

  def fromList(list: List[String]): Option[Client] =
    list match {
      case List(firstName, lastName) =>
        Some(Client(firstName, lastName))
      case _ => None
    }

  def fromXml(nodeSeq: NodeSeq): Option[Client] = {
    def option(label: String) =
      (nodeSeq \\ label).headOption.map(_.text)
    def listOption(label: String) =
      (nodeSeq \\ label).headOption.map {
        _.map(_.text).toList
      }
    for {
      firstName <- option("firstname")
      lastName <- option("lastname")
      products <- listOption("products")
    } yield Client(firstName, lastName, products)
  }
}
```

I also took the liberty of improving your code by eliminating mutability and making it generally more runtime safe.